# Eval directive's parameters angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have this html template :

```
<div width-watcher>
    <div parallax-bg parallax-active="!(tablet || mobile)">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

`width-watcher` exposes 3 boolean values: mobile, tablet and screen. No directive options here. I want to evaluate the expression `"!(tablet || mobile)"` to pass it to my second directive `parallax-bg`, to disable parallax on mobile devices.

I've tried the following (in `parallax-bg`):

- Use `scope.$eval(attr.parallaxActive)` returns `"undefined"`
- Use directly scope.parallaxActive with :

  - `"&"` => returns a function, when executed returns `"undefined"`
  - `"="` => returns `"undefined"`
  - `"@"` => returns `"!(tablet || mobile)"`

And I ran out of ideas. As english isn't my native language, I've probably missed some solutions on Google.

This is the code of my background-parallax directive :

```
.directive('parallaxBackground', function($window) {
return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    scope: {
        parallaxRatio: '@',
        parallaxOffset: '@',
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var scopeActive = scope.$eval(attrs.parallaxActive);
        var ...
        if(scopeActive){
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post your parallax-bg directive's link function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method, `scope.$eval(attr.parallaxActive)` is correct, but won't work if you bind the attribute value to your directive's scope.

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/v932rnfz/)

```
angular.module('myApp').directive(function() {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    transclude: true
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    alert(scope.$eval(iAttrs.parallaxActive));
  };
}
```

That said, my recommendation would be to turn your `widthWatcher` directive into a service using the factory strategy. This way, you can just inject it into any controller, directive, filter or other service and determine the screen type without relying on scope.

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/9e7411e1/)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('$widthWatcher', widthWatcherFactory)
  .directive('parallaxBg', parallaxBgDirective)
;

function widthWatcherFactory() {
  return {
    isMobile: isMobile,
    isScreen: isScreen,
    isTablet: isTablet
  };

  function getWidth() {
    return window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  }

  function isMobile() {
    return getWidth() < 600;
  }

  function isScreen() {
    return getWidth() > 960;
  }

  function isTablet() {
    return !isMobile() && !isScreen();
  }
}

function parallaxBgDirective($widthWatcher) {
  return {
    link: postLink,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    transclude: true
  };

  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    alert($widthWatcher.isScreen());
  };
}
```

**UPDATE**

To address the comment about values being undefined when the `parallaxBg` link function is called, I updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/v932rnfz/) to show the order in which link functions are called.

In order to understand what is going on, you need to understand [how directives are compiled](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#how-directives-are-compiled).

Comment: Sorry, after som tests, I figured out that your JsFiddle do "!(undefined)" that is evaluated at true... If you remove the "!" on the attribute, the alert shows "undefineed"...

Comment: That's because the parent scope's link function is called after the child directive's link function. I'll update the answer to also indicate that.

Comment: I've learned many things thanks to you :) I created a service which I give to the controllers who need it or even to my $rootScope when nescessary. Cheers !

Comment: That's awesome, glad I could help. But why would you ever need to store your service in $rootScope? I would question that approach. Better to explicitly inject a dependency than to implicitly require it to have been added to $rootScope elsewhere.

Comment: That's because I need it in the views of my whole application, especially in ng-class and ng-if. I also wanted to let my "paralax-background" as generic as possible so I give it a boolean value to turn it on or off, and not inject any dependencies. I also could add it as a dependency of my controllers, but rather than inject it to all of them to give it to all scopes, I prefer to give it to my $rootScope. Let me know if you think it's a bad idea/practice :) (and sorry for my english)

Comment: Using $rootScope to create "global "variables just doesn't sit right with me. I'd rather see you use a pure CSS solution, or custom directive like those used in Angular Material (e.g. show-sm, hide-lg, show-gt-md). Here is a JSFiddle I made a while back, which provides a pure CSS (using Sass) version of Angular Material's layout features (with optional JS for adding Angular directives): http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/dfrczu32/